# Proper way to use Composite Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns

I'm learning about composite design pattern and I can't understand how can I **treat every component the same** (Leaf and Composite) when whenever I try to add or remove component from the Leaf I should get an error(or nothing should happen). This seems to be horrible design to me beacuse it violates the rule of inheritance to treat objects the same. The only way would be to somehow differentiate Composite from Leaf and always be aware with what am I working with. But this takes me back to original problem...

**Component:**

```
public abstract class Equipment {
    private String name;
    
    protected Equipment(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String name(){
        return name;
    }
    
    
    public abstract int power();
    public abstract double netPrice();
    public abstract double discountPrice();
    
    public abstract void add(Equipment equipment);
    public abstract void remove(Equipment equipment);

    public Iterable<Equipment> createIterator(){
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

**Composite:**

```
public abstract class CompositeEquipment extends Equipment{
    private final List<Equipment> elements;
    
    protected CompositeEquipment(String name) {
        super(name);
        elements = new LinkedList<>();
    }
    
    @Override
    public double netPrice() {
        Iterable<Equipment> iter = createIterator();
        double total = 0;
        
        for (Iterator<Equipment> i = iter.iterator(); i.hasNext() ;) {
            Equipment next = i.next();
            total += next.netPrice();
        }
        
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Equipment> createIterator() {
        return elements;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Equipment equipment){
        elements.remove(equipment);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Equipment equipment){
        elements.add(equipment);
    }
    
}
```

**Leaf:**

```
public class FloppyDisk extends Equipment{

    public FloppyDisk(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int power() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public double netPrice() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public double discountPrice() {
        return 2.2;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Equipment equipment) {
        //we will do nothing here because thats the final element of the tree
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Equipment equipment) {
        //we will do nothing here because thats the final element of the tree
    }
    
}
```

**The problem I see:**

```
public void extendTheTree(Equipment equipment){
    equipment.add( new CompositeWithLeafs() );  //lets hope it is a Composite not a Leaf!!!
}
```

So how should I be using this pattern then or in what kind of scenario??? The only solution I see is to get rid of the Leaf concept and use only Composits.

Answer (score 3):

The root of your misunderstanding is that you took the methods that make sense for Leaf and the methods that make sense for Composite and put the union of those methods in `public abstract class Equipment`, that is your Component. This way, you ended up with a common ancestor for Leaf and Composite, part of which ancestor does not make sense for Leaf. I am talking about the `add` and `remove` methods, which do not make sense for Leaf, and therefore should not be part of Component in the first place. Whether you should use an abstract class or an interface to represent your Component is another issue and you can find perfect analyses in this site. But the fact is that Component should contain the intersection of Leaf's methods and Composite's methods, a set of methods that can be used on an object without knowing whether it is a Leaf or a Composite. More formally, Component should define the common interface which should be implemented by the Leaf and the Composite. If you go at it this way, you will find that you could never `add` to a Leaf, because the Component interface should not have such a method to override and the Leaf should no way have such a method too. For better or worse, you can only `add` to something that you know is a Composite.

Comment: do you mean to move `add` and `remove` methods to `CompositeEquipment` class?

Comment: @Tomek Yes, `add` and `remove` should not be in the Component, they should not be part of the Component interface. They should only be defined in Composite. After you do this, you will find that some design decisions come naturally.

Comment: but then you lose transparency because Leaves and Composites now have different interfaces. Which is not what this pattern is all about. I guess I'm trying to eat a cake and have a cake.

Comment: The emphasis is on the Component's methods, that is on the common interface. You need to be able to call the interface methods easily, without needing to find out if an object is a Leaf or a Composite and go through the tree accordingly. This pattern facilitates calling of interface methods. Adding and removing (to a Composite only) is a different story. You need to have a Composite to add to, that is for sure. Look at the Java example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: Leaf and Composite do not have different interfaces. They implement the same interface, but Composite has a few extra methods.

Comment: Again if you put methods for adding and removing to composite class then you lose transparency and you cannot add another components to the component even if it IS composite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116920/discussion-between-xnakos-and-tomek).

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) :

> There are two design variants for defining and implementing
> child-related operations like adding/removing a child component
> to/from the container (add(child)/remove(child)) and accessing a child
> component (getChild()):
>
> Design for uniformity: Child-related operations are defined in the
> Component interface. This enables clients to treat Leaf and Composite
> objects uniformly. But type safety is lost because clients can perform
> child-related operations on Leaf objects.
>
> Design for type safety: Child-related operations are defined only in
> the Composite class. Clients must treat Leaf and Composite objects
> differently. But type safety is gained because clients cannot perform
> child-related operations on Leaf objects.
>
> The Composite design pattern emphasizes uniformity over type safety.

In your example, you chose to design for uniformity by adding child-related operations (i.e. add/remove) in your Component (Equipment) abstract class, so you lose type safety because your clients can call add/remove methods on leaf (FloppyDisk) objects.

An interesting discussion about the pros and cons of each design, and when to prefer one design over the other, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384165/why-is-transparency-valued-over-safety-in-the-composite-pattern).